# Combine arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

I have two arrays as in the listing given below.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1.360, 0.085, -1.190, -0.340, 3.698]
```

I need to merge the values at each index so that I get a structure resembling `Resultant Array`.

```
Resultant Array = [[1, 1.360], [2, 0.085], [3, -1.190], [4, -0.340], [5, 3.698]]
```

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: `a.zip(b)` should do

Comment: How can I do this inside an view file in rails santhosh?

Comment: Do you mean erb/haml file? In erb, any code inside `<%  %>` will be executed, and inside `<%= %>` will be executed, and result will be output in the html

Comment: so if i do <%  @calculate[0].zip(@calculate[6]) %> will it work? Note: @calculate is an variable from my controller where i am storing all my arrays

Comment: How can I store this in an variable in my view.I am a newbie to rails and hence this noob questions.

Comment: Yes. You can do `<% combined_arr =  @calculate[0].zip(@calculate[6]) %>`

Comment: `Resultant Array` is an invalid name for a constant/variable. Give a working name.

Comment: Santhosh thanks a lot! Your suggestion and timely help nailed down my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip)

```
a.zip(b)
# => [[1, 1.36], [2, 0.085], [3, -1.19], [4, -0.34], [5, 3.698]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1.360, 0.085, -1.190, -0.340, 3.698]
```

You can also try an alternative:

```
[a,b].transpose
```

**Note:** *Use this when length of your array is same*

Comment: I tried your suggestion too it worked fine but I think 'zip' is an better way which is  exactly used to handle these type of situations, Hence I have accepted 'zip' as my answer. Thanks anyways for your suggestion too.

Comment: @AhkshayRavi Yes, I agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a.zip(b) #=> [[1,1.360],[2,0.085],[3,-1.190],[4,-0.340],[5,3.698]]
```

I didn't try it.

Source: [apidoc.com](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip)